# Jquery for intelligent search

Tags: jquery, html, events, key

I created this little example:

http://jsfiddle.net/fDavN/8391/

As you can see, I separated the image in four quadrats using the area-tag.

1. the first quadrat has the data-name: abc
2. the second quadrat has the data-name: def
3. the third quadrat has the data-name: ghi
4. the fourth quadrat has the data-name: jkl

Moreover, there is an input for a search.
What I want you to ask, if it's possible to type anything in the input and look if the input matches one of the data-name´s.

Scenario:

I type an "a" in the input => Every area with an "a" at the beginning of its data-name should stay as it is, but other area´s should get an opacity of "1". Is this possible using the keyup-event? e.g. :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#searchfield").keyup(function() { 
        //and so on..
    }
}
```

And how to make `jquery` searching for the `html`? I know how to do ajax etc.. But make `jquery` searching in the source code of website?

Greetings

Comment: This might help: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: yea i followed this: http://jsfiddle.net/fDavN/8398/  but there is no effect on the first area, when i type an "a" in the input :/  Could you refer to it? greetings